# ec2 iis web server 2019 long reques not processing error 400 Bad Request

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, iis-express

I am using jwt token of large size in url and my site page not opening instead it says 400 bad request. I checked by decreasing the characters and when characters of url less than 310 it worked but when url have more than 310 characters it not works. also specified the following to increase length but it still not works

```
<security>
        <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Comment: What is your http sub-status code? Only 400 is difficult to figure out which part of the URL is the problem.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/

Comment: its way saying bad request

Comment: but I not want solution now as I have moved to other server which works fine

Comment: Do you mean that it can work fine now?